# Material-UI how to use forwardRef in MenuItem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

If you return MenuItem in Array.map, error occur when I press Select.

Code

```
const MenuItems: React.FC<{ items: number[] }> = (props) => {
  const { items } = props;
  return (
    <>
      {items.map((i) => {
        return (
          <MenuItem key={i} value={i}>
            {i}
          </MenuItem>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Error

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.
Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

So I want to rewrite it to forwardRef, but I don't know the type of ref. Is it possible to use forwardRef for MenuItem in the first place?

Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your problem is from the code you've shown us.
There is no use of refs in it, maybe you could show us where you're trying to pass in refs or what you have on your items prop?

Comment: I want to avoid deep nesting, but I get a message that a forwardRef is needed. I don't know what to pass for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem: Separation between `Select` and `MenuItem`

The Material UI `Select` component [expects](https://material-ui.com/api/select/#props) to have `MenuItem` components as its direct children.  It will pass a `ref` to its children.  In your case, the child of the the `Select` would be your `MenuItems` component, which doesn't accept a `ref`.  I don't recommend ref forwarding here.  Instead, you need to redesign your component structure so that there is no separation between the `Select` and the mapped `MenuItem`.

Here's one example:

```
import { MenuItem, Select, SelectProps } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useState } from "react";

type MyMenuProps = {
  items: number[];
  value: number;
} & Pick<SelectProps, "onChange">;

const MyMenu: React.FC<MyMenuProps> = (props) => {
  const { items, value, onChange } = props;
  return (
    <Select value={value} onChange={onChange}>
      {items.map((i) => {
        return (
          <MenuItem key={i} value={i}>
            {i}
          </MenuItem>
        );
      })}
    </Select>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);
  return (
    <MyMenu
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(parseInt(e.target.value))}
      items={[1, 2, 3, 4]}
    />
  );
}
```